# Neo4J - How to 2 import CSV files with relationship between them?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I do have two CSV files: employee and department. I can load them into `Neo4J` with the following Queries:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Path/to/myCSVfile/depart.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Department{departmentID:toInt(row.id),name:row.name, depart_manager:toInt(row.department_manager)});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Path/to/myCSVfile/Empl.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Employee{employeeID:toInt(row.id),firstName:row.first_name, lastName:row.last_name, email:row.email, 
startDate:row.startdate, birthDay:row.birthdate, function:row.function, departementId:row.depart_id});
```

Now I want to add the relationship between them... in other words, each employee should belong to a specific department (depart_id).

The CSV files have been already imported and I can display the nodes for each label.

How can reach this? Is it possible to do it after the import with a script/query, or should I reimport them with a different script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try adding the desired relationship in the end of the second LOAD CSV statement.

Like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Path/to/myCSVfile/depart.csv" AS depRow
CREATE (:Department{departmentID:toInt(depRow.id),name:depRow.name, depart_manager:toInt(depRow.department_manager)})
WITH *
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Path/to/myCSVfile/Empl.csv" AS empRow
CREATE (employee:Employee{employeeID:toInt(empRow.id),firstName:empRow.first_name, lastName:empRow.last_name, email:empRow.email, 
startDate:empRow.startdate, birthDay:empRow.birthdate, function:empRow.function, departmentId:empRow.depart_id})
WITH employee
// Adding relation between employee and department
MATCH (dep:Department {departmentID : employee.departmentId})
CREATE (employee)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(dep)
```

Comment: Error: `WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH (line 6, column 1 (offset: 478))
"MATCH (dep:Department{departmentID:row.depart_id})"`. I think `WITH employee, row` should come after `MATCH`. what do you think?

Comment: Great! works. Sorry, what about to display (Table and/or Graph) the employees with relationships would it be: `MATCH (n:Employee)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(d:Department)
RETURN n LIMIT 25`. I unfortunately get: `(no changes, no records)`

Comment: @k.vincent What is the return of `MATCH(n) RETURN n`?

Comment: I get both (result as a Graph) - Employee and Department. I want to reach a graph with relationships... let's say arrows which indicate the employee relationship to department.

Comment: When tryiny: `MATCH (n1)--(n2)
RETURN n1, n2 LIMIT 50` Looks like there is no relationship between Employee and Department. `(no changes, no records)`

Comment: @k.vincent seems to be a typo error. The `CREATE` statement was using `departementId`, but the `MATCH` using `departmentId`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. 
Now I did new try with a small change. I renamed the column `department_id` in `employee` to: `department_id_chief`, but still no relationship. My Query now looks like:
`.... // Adding relation between employee and department
MATCH (dep:Department {departmentID: employee.department_id_chief})
CREATE (employee)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(dep)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155771/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-bruno-peres).